# DynamoDB fine-grained access control: is it possible to use ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:email}?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

My users have Cognito accounts.

According to [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups) we can restrict access to the DynamoDB API with policy like that:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb: <REGION>:<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:table/<TABLE>"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Looks pretty straightforward for my case when index key is `email` (and primary sort key is `utc`), so I adjusted example above to this one:

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123456789123:table/history",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                    "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:email}"
                ],
                "dynamodb:Attributes": [
                    "email",
                    "utc",
                    "updated",
                    "isNew"
                ]
            }
        }
```

But I keep getting the error `AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::9876543210:assumed-role/policyname/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123456789123:table/history`.

I tried my js http call with `*` permissions and it works, so pitfall only with this policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:email}` is not a valid policy variable. It's not resolving to your users' email addresses.

It is a shame as most developers, like yourself, would find the users email address more intuitive than using `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub` or `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud`.

Comment: I thought that email address is a good unique identity of a user. Hmm, now I need to create a new table with another hash key or use API Gateway with Lambda :(

Comment: Exactly. Maybe raise this in AWS support too. Maybe they will add the feature one day.

Answer (score 2):

In [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230067) I found that I can use
`${cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:sub}`
This is not email but in future I can [list users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) with this `sub`.

Comment: Did you make anything special to get the ${cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:sub} working? I have an IdToken from a Cognito User Pool that is send to an ApiGateway with Cognito Authorizer. The mapping template works for setting the user sub as part of the message that is send to dynamodb, but the policy which checks if the user is allowed to write to the row using the ${cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:sub} is not working. If a hardcore it to the sub of the user everything works. So it must be this expression does not return anything or something wrong...

Comment: I have the same issue where I'm getting denied writing with the UserPool Id to Dynamodb with the IAM leading keys policy being either ${cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:sub} or ${cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_XXXX:sub}

Comment: I've got an answer from an AWS Dev Member regarding this topic. Have a look here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=305485